# rendering a file in python using pygal - ascii code error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6, pygal

I am trying to create a pygal chart in python and saving it to  a .svg file.

```
#Creating pygal charts
pie_chart = pygal.Pie(style=DarkSolarizedStyle, legend_box_size = 20, pretty_print=True)
pie_chart.title = 'Github-Migration Status Chart (in %)'
pie_chart.add('Intro', int(intro))
pie_chart.add('Parallel', int(parallel))
pie_chart.add('In Progress', int(in_progress) )
pie_chart.add('Complete', int(complete))
pie_chart.render_to_file('../../../../../usr/share/nginx/html/TeamFornax/githubMigration/OverallProgress/overallProgress.svg')
```

This simple piece of code seems to give the error -

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/ec2-user/githubr/migrationcharts.py", line 161, in <module>
>     pie_chart.render_to_file('../../../../../usr/share/nginx/html/TeamFornax/githubMigration/OverallProgress/overallProgress.svg')
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pygal/ghost.py", line 149, in
> render_to_file
>     f.write(self.render(is_unicode=True, **kwargs))   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pygal/ghost.py", line 112, in render
>     .render(is_unicode=is_unicode))   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pygal/graph/base.py", line 293, in
> render
>     is_unicode=is_unicode, pretty_print=self.pretty_print)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pygal/svg.py", line 271, in render
>     self.root, **args)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1010, in
> tostring
>     return string.join(data, "")   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/string.py", line 318, in join
>     return sep.join(words) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

try to decode the path string to `unicode` that you send to `render_to_file`.
such like:

```
pie_chart.render_to_file('path/to/overallProgress.svg'.decode('utf-8'))
```

the decoding charset should be consistent with your file encoding.